# No wifi interface ArchLinux

Tags: archlinux

After installation, no wifi interface shows up when I run ip link(just lo and enp0s31f6). I installed networkmanager, wpa_supplicant, network-manager-applet and dialog. Wifi menu shows the error invalid interface specification

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you are missing drivers.
You probably need to install one of the wireless drivers:

- ipw2200-fw
- broadcom-wl

I also suggest to check `dmesg`, `lshw`, `lsusb` and `lspci`. It depends on if you have an internal wifi card or an external usb wifi device.

You could try to use a different kernel version, too (linux-lts vs linux).

And you should use [**iwd**](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-improved-wifi-via-iwd/17795/61) instead of wpa_supplicant. It's a new internet wireless daemon with a much better codebase.